# tennis logistic reggresion model

Tags: logistic, classification, predictive-models

I would like to do some logistic model for predicting match result. I have 450 observations of Cibulkova's matches.

Columns:  age, height, rank, surface, hand and same for opponent + match result.

How should I add age and rank difference into model? I think, it is not good to add just simple difference: rankME-rankOPPONENT because match: rank 5 vs rank 10 is different than rank 105 vs rank 110. I am sure that I should reduce the rank difference scale from 1 (1,2,3,4,5,...) to e.g. 5-10 (0,5,10,15,20...) because estimated parameter will be low ~ 0 (no significant).
Same for age difference. I think there is some teoretically "break-point" age from when players start to get worse,e.g. 25 years old has advantage against 20 years old, but 30y. has't.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use splines for the effect of both rank difference and age.  That will let the relationship with the dependent variable take virtually any shape. Various splines are available, if you search both this site and elsewhere you will find a wealth of material.  They are available in R, SAS and (I am sure) other packages as well.

By the way, your idea that grouping rank differences in the way you suggest will help with significance is incorrect.  Categorizing continuous variables increases type I and type II error.  It is very rarely a good idea to do this and this is not one of those times.